# Table column widths different for table with/without data

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have found something unusual and was wondering if this is intentional behaviour and if there is a fix for this. I would ideally like to stay within bootstrap without having to specify specific widths.

I am using twitter bootstrap to format a table. However when there is a table with no data the column widths are different to a table with data, i.e. a body with rows.

I have created a jsFiddle to demo this. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osL9u4w3/3/)

Here is the html.

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="col-md-12 category-header"><span class="">Turbo</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table no-margin">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left col-md-1">Part No.</th>
                        <th class="text-left col-md-3">Description</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-md-3">Notes</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Dates</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-md-1">Stock</th>
                        <th class="text-right col-md-1">RRP</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>    
                        <td class="col-md-1">ISTB10768R</td>
                        <td class="col-md-3">REMANUFACTURED TURBO</td>
                        <td title="" class="col-md-3 text-center"></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 text-center"></td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
                                <i title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-check amber black-tooltip" data-original-title="Less than three units in stock"></i>

                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 text-right">£370.00</td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 text-right">
                            <span data-part-number="ISTB10768R" data-part-id="564" href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart add-to-cart-btn pink  " title="Add To Cart  ">Add</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 category-header"><span class="">Gear Boxes</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table no-margin">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left col-md-1">Part No.</th>
                        <th class="text-left col-md-3">Description</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-md-3">Notes</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Dates</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-md-1">Stock</th>
                        <th class="text-right col-md-1">RRP</th>
                        <th class="col-md-1"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody/>
            </table>
            <div class="missing-parts">Please call the sales team for price and availability</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the columns of the table "<td>" change width according to the size of the text or data that's in it, that's how it usually works, unless you want to fix the width than you have to customize the css.

Comment: So with regards to giving each column a class, col-md-3, has no real effect?

Comment: you should use the class col-md-* only on the <td> not on the <th>, but when the media changes the width of the col-md-* changes

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but there is a problem in the code you provided(specifically in the second table), perhaps a typo. Which is causing the overflow.

**Second table code you provided**

```
    <table class="table no-margin">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left col-md-1">Part No.</th>
                <th class="text-left col-md-3">Description</th>
                <th class="text-center col-md-3">Notes</th>
                <th class="text-center col-md-2">Dates</th>
                <th class="text-center col-md-1">Stock</th>
                <th class="text-right col-md-1">RRP</th>
                <th class="col-md-1"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody/>
    </table>
    <div class="missing-parts">Please call the sales team for price and availability</div>
```

As you can see the `<tbody/>` is wrong. There is no starting `<tbody>` tag & the closing tag should be `</tbody>`. Also there the `missing-parts` in nowhere inside the table body. It is outside the table body and that's why the weird behavior.

I have provided the correct code below. Here is the [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osL9u4w3/4/). Works fine now.

**Corrected table code**

```
  <table class="table no-margin">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left col-md-1">Part No.</th>
            <th class="text-left col-md-3">Description</th>
            <th class="text-center col-md-3">Notes</th>
            <th class="text-center col-md-2">Dates</th>
            <th class="text-center col-md-1">Stock</th>
            <th class="text-right col-md-1">RRP</th>
            <th class="col-md-1"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="missing-parts">Please call the sales team for price and availability</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Very important thing to note here is that, even though you have not specified any number of data columns under the first `<tr>`, it automatically assigns the `<td>` values to its respective `<th>s`.

In other words. If you mention only one `<td>`, it will automatically become the data of the first header ie. "Part No.". Which also means the **the width of the data takes the width of the header it corresponds to**(just like the top table). Try adding another `<td>` inside the same table row, you will understand.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue of inconsistent column widths.

Comment: It actually does. How you ask ? I have updated the answer. Please check

Comment: Or if your too lazy to read the explanation, **you can just add another `<td>` to the same row**, you will see the change what you were looking for :)

Comment: Again, it seems to me, as the PartNo column expands, the class col-md-* has no constraint on it. So the PartNo column expands, which I dont want it to do. Im just curious why the difference in widths when a table has no data and when one does, even using the same col-md-* classes.

Comment: Did you know or notice the top expands too buddy... Even the top table expands according to the data. If data removed that behaves the same as well. Even on the top table col-md-* has no constraint on it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Looks like I will have to put it all into a single table, or create fixed widths. Thank you again.